# Getting an Image to Appear Below Another When Clickd

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple slider set-up with about 10 images.

I would like to be able to have the user click on one of the images in the slider and as a result that image appears below the slider.

The slider still remains above the newly placed image.

I don't want a light box or a modal window, I would like the image to appear on the page beneath the slider.

I'm wondering how to do this in JavaScript or CSS or Bootstrap?

I haven't been able to find anything on Google for this, so I appreciate any help that could be given.

---

Comment: I'm honestly not even sure where to start, I just don't know to do it as lame as that sounds

Comment: What you're asking is too general, in order to answer it one would have to pretty much do it scratch for you. You should do a bit more research come up with a starting point and as you run into problems post questions with your sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a fairly vague question, I have a fairly vague answer. This involves using jQuery, and will insert items in your slider into a div on each click. Feel free to clarify any more specifics that could help me provide a better answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#slider li").click(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    $("#page-beneath-slider").append(html);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h2>Stuff beneath the slider</h2>
<div id="page-beneath-slider"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for my vague question but your vague answer was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: One other question is there a way to modify that code so each new image clicked replaces the image we just placed in the <div id="page-beneath-slider"> rather than a new image appearing next to it?

Comment: Yes. replace `.append()` with `.html()`